# Umbrella term for travel 'ingredients': hotel, flight, car rental, ...?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the catholic/encompassing/general term for these travel essentials? 'Travel items' is wrong; they refer to actual physical objects. 'Travel necessities' is also wrong; they technically aren't mandatory for travel. To wit, what are some nouns that can replace all of the bolded:

> Could I please return to you about attending your ceremony only after you decide on its location? I ask because the availability of **hotels, flights, car rentals,** .... might prove difficult to book once I learn about the location at a later date.

Please also advise if I can improve the writing in the  above quote, especially the last sentence?

Comment: I'd say "*... after I've worked out the **details of my itinerary***".

Comment: By the way, the word "*catholic*" isn't used the way you're using it here in English any more. In contemporary English, "*Catholic*" is used exclusively as a proper noun for a particular religion or set of religious traditions.

Comment: @DanBron Thank you for your advice once again! Did I misunderstand or misuse definition 1 at http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/catholic? Or is it just obsolete?

Comment: @Up, no, you understood correctly; it is simply that that definition is now obsolete.

Comment: @DanBron +1 to all your comments. Thank you effusively! I'll beware of it.

Comment: What comes to mind is _arrangements_, but that is quite vague and would be out of place in your example sentence, I'm afraid.

Comment: @DanBron When did'st thou declare it obsolete, King Dan? I must have missed its announcement in the newspaper.

Comment: @WS2, I'm not sure newspapers have announced print news is obsolete, either.

Comment: @DanBron Not for us long in the tooth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Arrangements* (Travel arrangements) is the word you need.

> Could I please return to you about attending your ceremony only after you decide on its location? I ask because **travel arrangements** might prove difficult to book once I learn about the location at a later date.

---

I can't find an easy source of a definition of 'travel arrangements' but here's a quote from Wikipedia.

> In addition to dealing with ordinary tourists most travel agencies have a separate department devoted to making travel arrangements for business travelers and some travel agencies specialize in commercial and business travel only.

<sub>Wikipedia contributors, "Travel agency," Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Travel_agency&oldid=633727772 (accessed November 18, 2014).</sub>

---

Here's a link to a page specifically about travel arrangements. http://traveltips.usatoday.com/travel-arrangements-13279.html (from USAToday).

> Whether you are booking an exotic vacation or business trip, making travel arrangements can be a chore. It takes time to find the best prices and coordinate logistics through each step of your journey.

---

And with thanks to [JLG](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/18655) here is a definition from "web2.uvcs.uvic.ca"

> plans for where and when you are travelling, how you are travelling, and where you are sleeping

which can be found at http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/courses/glossary/popup.aspx?TermID=13094

Comment: Here is [a pretty good definition.](http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/courses/glossary/popup.aspx?TermID=13094)

Answer (score -2):

I'd use travel "[accommodations](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/accommodations)". So,

> I ask because the availability of travel accommodations might prove difficult.

It's common in travel literature, and it can include all of those sets.

In fact, sense 5 of the link covers the three examples in your post.

However, accomodations shouldn't be confused with "amenities", which would be things like wifi, laundry, kitchen, etc--those luxuries you might find in individual accommodations.

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, but I will offer a possible explanation: I would usually understand _accommodations_ to refer to places to stay, specifically to spend the night. Flights and car rentals do not come to mind when someone mentions the need to book accommodations.