# Catholic with a small c

Tags: word-usage

When Conservative is spelled with a capital C it usually refers to the Conservative and Unionist Party of Great Britain. Spelled with a small c, it becomes the adjective *conservative* meaning *averse to change or innovation and holding traditional values. People, in Britain at any rate will sometimes describe themselves as 'conservative with a small c'.

Similarly Catholic, spelled with a capital C usually refers to the Roman Catholic church, and/or its members. But spelled with a small c, it means: *a wide variety of things; all embracing*. So I may describe my taste in food as *catholic* meaning I am willing to try anything.

But whilst I have heard plenty of people describe their tastes as 'catholic', I have never heard anyone use the expression *catholic with a small c*.

Would it generally be understood and accepted into mainstream conversation if someone did. If not, what is the term, meaning 'all embracing', (apart, of course from 'all embracing').

Comment: _Plenty_ of people, no less? I wonder if that’s conditioned by geography, or perhaps age. I have heard it, but quite rarely. As a tangential tidbit, some other Germanic languages (certain Danish and Norwegian, and I believe at least Swedish too) use _Catholic_ to mean ‘woozy, confused, befuddled’, and _Greek Catholic_ (as in the Eastern Orthodox Church) to mean ‘completely and utterly indifferent’. Both quite different meanings, but also both attributable to the historical meaning of _catholic_, which is ‘over everything’ or ‘concerning it all’, _vel sim_.

Comment: well, catholic with a small C is used in one of the prayers in the catholic mass each week.  So Catholics might know what you are talking about.

Comment: Now that I’ve happened to come across [the question that sparked this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208872/umbrella-term-for-travel-ingredients-hotel-flight-car-rental), I’m glad to see I’m not the only one who thinks it’s rather an esoteric word. That does leave the question of _where_ the word still enjoys some remaining vigour, though.

Comment: Is your question whether *catholic* has become obsolete (which seems to be how most of the answerers have interpreted it) or why you have never heard the precise expression *catholic **with a small c*** (in contrast to *conservative with a small c*, which one does hear from time to time)?

Comment: @jsw29 It is the latter of those two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a service, I asked a priest about the creed which reads, "one holy, catholic church" and said I thought I was attending an Anglican church.

He replied, "'Catholic' with a small c."

That was 20 years ago, so it would be understood in religious settings at the very least.

Comment: It is nice to know there are people for whom the English language exists beyond their own narrow lexicons. Someone on one of these pages yesterday pointed out *catholic* as 'obsolete' (other than in Roman Catholic). For those who declare words 'obsolete', presumably the works of Shakespeare, indeed anything published prior to about 1950 is also 'obsolete'.

Comment: @WS2 It bothers me that there are words considered obsolete that are of perfectly good use and without alternatives. Consider how often we say "the day after tomorrow" and "the day before yesterday", yet the supposedly-obsolete words "overmorrow" and "ereyesterday" mean precisely those, respectively.

Comment: @Ws2 I was the one who declared *catholic* as a synonym for the secular *comprehensive* obsolete, and nothing in these answers has led me to change that opinion. In fact, to the contrary, it has reinforced my belief no one in the modern world uses it this way. The most upvoted answer agrees directly that the word is obsolete and only used in the sense of a religion which recognizes the pope, and this answer you accepted says he heard it once, 20 years ago, spoken by a priest, at which time he thought he priest had meant Catholic, big C. [cont'd]

Comment: [cont'd] Which means even a religious man, *20 years ago* had been conditioned to understand the word in the Roman Catholic sense. Seems to me "catholic, small c" is used only by Anglicans as an apologia: "We're Catholic, but not Catholic-Catholic". The only other answer agrees with that sentiment and declares the only non-religious context he's seen the word in is a humanitarian one, and can't see his way to agreeing with your usage of "catholic tastes". In other words, we are not *declaring* "catholic, small c", obsolete, we are *observing* it so. It's dead and gone. I'm sorry for your loss.

Comment: @DanBron Are you declaring the works of Shakespeare 'obsolete', since they contain much vocabulary which is seldom used?

Comment: @Ws2, I don't think you quite understand what the word "*obsolete*" means. The *works* of Shakespeare enjoy *enormous* popularity and currency. There are entire theatre troops, TV shows, books, university curricula, etc dedicated to the *works* of Shakespeare. Specific *words* of Shakespeare, by contrast, have all but vanished from the modern lexicon and *are* obsolete. In other words, *petard*, like *catholic*, *overmorow*, and *ereyesterday* **is** obsolete. Yet "*hoist by his own petard*" isn't. ***Because people still use it.***

Comment: @ColinT Five stars to you for raising those. I shall do all I can to re-invigorate their use. I have already remarked to my wife that I am looking forward to *overmorrow*, when I am due to reach three-score and ten years and all our family are joining us for the week-end.

Comment: "The creed" is the Apostle's Creed (see my answer).

Comment: @WS2 Congratulations and many happy returns for … too late … for tomorrow! (70 is the new 50.)

Comment: @DanBron And since I know someone who uses the word *catholic* in that way, you had better let me know what the penalty is for doing so, so I can warn him. Is it something like six months for a first offence, of use of an *obsolete* word?

Comment: @WS2 The penalty is fairly steep: people having no idea what you're on about, and dismissing you as an out of touch whacko.

Comment: @DanBron I shall be proud to be "an out of touch whacko". I trust the ale still tastes the same when you are one of those?

Comment: @WS2 I can't guarantee the taste of ale is catholic. It might've been ereyesterday, but times change.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think it would be universally understood, chiefly because most English speakers don't realize there is a meaning to "catholic" other than "the Christian church that recognizes the Pope in Rome as its spiritual head".

That wouldn't make it a useless thing to say though. For instance my (non Catholic) church occasionally has us recite the [Apostle's Creed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostles'_Creed), which contains the line:

> I believe in the Holy Spirit, the holy catholic Church, the communion of saints, ...

This can cause a lot of confusion. I had a visiting Catholic friend ask me about it, and I've even seen some hymnals take the step of adding the unpronounced parenthetical "(universal)" after the word "catholic".

**If you are looking for a good replacement word, I'd go with those protestant churches and use "universal".**

Answer (score 4):

The collocation "catholic tastes" is certainly not obsolete. A quick look at books.google.com/ngram for recent uses (since 1982) of "catholic tastes" provides plenty of examples ranging from things like Shostakovich's "catholic taste in music “from Bach to Offenbach,” in gypsy music, street songs, and the music hall, were well established. Jazzderived rhythms, textures, and instrumental color had been assimilated into much of his music" to the Northern Hemisphere Minke whale's "catholic tastes" as opposed to its cousins in the Southern Hemisphere: "in the Northern Hemisphere, it has more catholic tastes and much fish is eaten."

Comment: This is definitely the case, but I wonder if "catholic" is used outside this expression. It wouldn't be the only English word commonly used only in a single expression (e.g. petard).

Answer (score 2):

I'd understand it right away (but I cannot claim to be representative of what people would "generally" understand).

As an alternative,

- I eat anything
- I'll try anything [once]!
- I'm omnivorous
- I'm easy to please
- I'd like what you're having
- I'm a flexitarian <-- a new favourite

It wouldn't occur to me to describe a taste in food as "catholic", though:

- Because it has a religious tone, which because of [Matthew 15:11](http://www.biblestudytools.com/matthew/15-11-compare.html) doesn't sound appropriate to me
- Because I think of it as "accepting" (of other people) ... I accept them, I'm not going to eat them!

https://www.google.com/search?q=catholic+etymology suggests that a good synonym of "catholic" is "universal".

Comment: I'm atypical because my Dad was a Professor of Classics and a Catholic.

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that this is an example of a word becoming obsolete because of the potential for confusion with other usages, but continues to be used in certain phrases where there's no danger of confusion. Certainly in educated British usage, it's not unusual to talk of having catholic tastes - but it's clear that one is not talking about a type of religious cannibalism! But there's other words that can be used for "not fussy" in other contexts, so there's no need to use "catholic" and then distinguish it as "small-C".

The two meanings of C/conservative are distinct but hard to substitute in many contexts, hence the need to distinguish them. But in general "small-C" conservative is used far less in the UK than in the US and synonyms found for it, in the same way that synonyms are found for small-C "catholic".

Answer (score 0):

Words, fortunately or not, depending on your attachment to them, change with usage, and there's nothing any professor or department in a university can do about it, though they might like to. I've heard writers and editors stamp their feet and rail against the wind about how the word *impact* morphed from a noun to an adverb, usually in the form *impacted.*  "The only impacted is an impacted tooth!" they would say. But language doesn't care a bit, it has its own life. *Impact* contains a sense of implied action within it, so over time, due to usage and what seemed right to people, that action emerged and it became an adverb.

Now, the word catholic is a kind of reversal of that example. Catholic in the original sense, and in the sense the Catholic Church meant it, was universal, containing all others, widely embracing, something like that. (Which, as it turned out, was the exact opposite of the actual Catholic Church in practice.) But the huge growth and spread of the Catholic Church onto the present has subsumed the word - it can't be thought of by most people as anything but Catholic with a capital C. In fact, now if someone says a person is very catholic in their tastes, it usually means the opposite of the correct meaning, and means that person is buttoned down, rigid and dogmatic. So, sorry to say, the small 'c' catholic word, in its correct meaning, is close to dead, in actual usage.