# What is a good word for 'being a group where different beliefs are practiced'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is a good word for *being a group where different beliefs are practiced*?

I.e. wearing a headscarf, being a atheist or doing a silent prayer for diner are common.

*Secular* means an organisation is not religious by itself but implies we expect people to be secular. And *pluriform* could also cover cultural properties but hasn't that much to do with religions.

Comment: Can you provide a sample sentence in your question with a blank where the word would go?

Comment: Yes. We are a christian sports club. We are a secular sports club. We are a ... sports club.

Comment: The US is known as ***pluralistic***. But that speaks to more than just matters of faith (it includes nationality, creed, sexuality, etc). So, more specifically, in certain parts here, different sects of Protestant Christians, normally at odds with each other on questions of both scripture and theology, gather together under what they call a ***Big Tent***, where they celebrate the beliefs they have in common, and put aside their differences (for a time, anyway).

Comment: What about multi-faith group?

Comment: Pluralistic is definitely the term I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Saturana Calling atheism a faith will definitely fright certain people. Also people who simply _don't know_ are welcome.

Comment: "We are a non-denominational sports club"?

Answer (score 3):

You could say your group is [diverse](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=define:+diverse):

> showing a great deal of variety; very different.
>
> "a culturally diverse population"
>
> synonyms:  various, sundry, manifold, multiple; varied, varying, miscellaneous, assorted, mixed, diversified, divergent, heterogeneous, a mixed bag of; different, differing, distinct, unlike, dissimilar; literarydivers, myriad

Or [eclectic](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=define:+eclectic):

> deriving ideas, style, or taste from a broad and diverse range of sources.
>
> a person who derives ideas, style, or taste from a broad and diverse range of sources.

Answer (score 0):

I would say [multicultural](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/multicultural).

Culture doesn't have to be synonymous with race or nationality - in fact, almost everything a person does or believes is part of their culture. Therefore, *multicultural* would probably be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the adjective [*multi-religious*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/multireligious) which means:

> (of a country, society, etc) having followers of more than one
>   religion: '*Exotic temples litter the island, reflecting its broad,
>   multi-religious culture.*'

[Collins Online Dictionary]

You could call your group "multi-religious group".

Even though 17.6% of the population didn't have a religion in Singapore in 1988 based on [the link](http://www.academia.edu/1903946/Secular_state_multi-religious_society_the_patterning_of_religion_in_Singapore), Singapore was called "multi-religious society".

Answer (score 0):

**catholic**

Of course with the meaning described at [Catholic with a small c](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208949/catholic-with-a-small-c).

> **catholic**:  a wide variety of things; all embracing.

That option is probably likely to cause confusion and/or fun, so more realistically consider ...

> **broad church**: (usually not capitals) a group or movement which embraces a wide and varied number of views, approaches, and opinions
>    -- [collinsdictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/broad-church)